# banner move on 1 way with owl.carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I use Owl Carousel to generate carousel banners, but if I always want to change images on fixed and same direction (i.e. move to right). Even the image is the last one, and then move to first one. (i.e. http://www.walmart.com/)

**HTML**:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
    <img src="images/pc/indexSlide_01.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/pc/indexSlide_01.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/pc/indexSlide_01.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, the js is just simple code,

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: 2000,

    paginationSpeed: 1000,
    goToFirstSpeed: 2000,
    singleItem: true,
    autoHeight: true
});
```

is there any example be refered? Thank you for your helping.

Comment: Do u have answer for this question